# How to disable legends in GeoListPlot and other geographic functions?

Tags: labeling, geography

How can I hide or disable the automatic legend feature of GeoListPlot?
I have the following code and results:

```
GeoListPlot[
 List /@ (Tooltip[#, #["Name"]] & /@ RandomEntity["Country", 40])]
```

My goal is to remove the area with the Legends. I looked at the Guide for Legends but didn't see any Boolean settings such as DisableLegended->True.
[image]

Comment: just use `PlotLegends -> None` in `GeoListPlot`?

Answer (score 2):

`t = GeoListPlot[ List /@ (Tooltip[#, #["Name"]] & /@ RandomEntity["Country", 4])]` is your plot; then

- `t[[1]]` is the plot
- `t[[2]]` is the `Placed` legend

[image]

Or use `First` and `Last` to get these items.